# How to resolve HTTP status 403 error when Flutter app connects to a https resource and VPN is active on the device?

Tags: flutter, dio

I have a Flutter app that connects to a https resource (*https mydomain dot com/loginFrm*) to process some data.

When the VPN on the device is up and running, the Flutter app cannot connect to the https resource and gives an HTTP status error [403]. The error occurs when the Flutter app is run both on actual Android phone and iPhone.

I am using DIO package v4.0.4 and the app is developed using Flutter v3.0.5 and Dart v2.17.6.

Any idea on how to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you try a different VPN

Comment: @Georgina Thanks for your quick reply. It works when the VPN is connected to a server located in the same country as where the https resource is located. But when the VPN is connected to a server in different country the 403 error occurs.

Comment: I am a foreigner in china so i always use vpns (Google cannot be accessed in China). I believe your issue could be with the API your using. Sometimes I also have issues connecting to a database like firebase when using some vpns (It could also be the VPN).

Answer (score 0):

Your server or government is most likely blocking the request based on location or a spam filter, there is nothing Flutter or Dart can do to fix your VPN.